# How to use multiple filters on an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a working repeater that places the fields for each page on the appropriate page.

```
<div ng-repeat="p in model.pages">
    <div ng-repeat="f in model.fields | filter: { pageNumber: p.pageNumber }:true">
        <div class="pdf-field">{{f.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I need it to filter out any fields that either don't have the `isTask` property or if the property equals false.  The code below kills the entire repeater and includes nothing.

```
<div ng-repeat="p in model.pages">
    <div ng-repeat="f in model.fields | filter: { pageNumber: p.pageNumber }:true | filter: { isTask: true }">
        <div class="pdf-field">{{f.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create a custom filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combined both of them into single filter `object`.

```
ng-repeat="f in model.fields | filter: { pageNumber: p.pageNumber, isTask: true }"
```

---

Rather the better approach would be doing this filtering in controller side once. So that the application will be more performant.

```
model.pages.filter(function(page){
   page.fields = model.fields.filter(function(field){
      return field.pageNumber === page.pageNumber && field.isTask;
   });
   return page.fields.length;
});

<div ng-repeat="p in model.pages">
    <div ng-repeat="f in p.fields">
        <div class="pdf-field">{{f.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `ngIf`

```
<div ng-repeat="p in model.pages">
    <div ng-repeat="f in model.fields | filter: { pageNumber: p.pageNumber }:true" ng-if="isTask=true">
        <div class="pdf-field">{{f.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked also but I had to change to `ng-if="f.isTask == true"`